Nginx stop work when one service is down
I was working on configuring a locations.conf file for reverse proxy with nginx, however, when one of the services set in locations is turned off/paused in docker, nginx simply stops working and responding, how can I get around this problem, where even the service is off nginx will work/start normally.
I wonder if there is some kind of try-catch that could be used in this case, or something similar.
Last nginx logs before stopping:
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2024/12/04 19:10:42 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "microsservico_whatsapp_front" in /etc/nginx/locations.conf:16
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "microsservico_whatsapp_front" in /etc/nginx/locations.conf:16

The location I have set:
    location /microsservico_whatsapp_front/ {
      proxy_pass http://microsservico_whatsapp_front:7007;
      rewrite ^/microsservico_whatsapp_front(.*)$ $1 break;
   } 

The docker-compose file:
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: dev_nginx
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/proxy.conf
      - ./fastcgi.conf:/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf
      - ./locations.conf:/etc/nginx/locations.conf
      - ./images:/usr/local/share/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - default
networks:
  default:
    external:
            name: bluenetwork

Any suggestions to help me? Please

Add your docker-compose.yml file to your question, please.

Of course! Tomorrow when I arrive at my laboratory I will add

The error indicates that your nginx cannot resolve the name "microsservico_whatsapp_front" - its that simple. How you fix it depends on how you expect it to be resolved. OTOH its far from clear why turning off a "service" (unless its the DNS service) causes this to happen.

Hey @IvanShatsky I added my docker-compose file, hopefully it helps to better understand the problem!

Not of much help, unfortunatelly. I don't see what type of that bluenetwork since you're refering to it in your docker-compose.yml file as external. Is the microsservico_whatsapp_front a service name from another docker-compose setup or an nginx upstream name, defined via upstream microsservico_whatsapp_front { ... } nginx configuration block?
